# how add link to excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, report

I'm generating an csv file that is opened by excel and converted to xlsx manually.
The csv contains some path to .txt files.
Is it possible to build the file path in such way that when the csv is converted to xlsx , they became clickable hyperlinks ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're manually converting to xlsx, its probably better to just use the [hyperlink function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) in excel in a new column. Or if you really want to go the python route, then create a column that takes your path column and generate the hyperlink e.g. `link = '=hyperlink(path_to_file,"filename")'`

Answer (score 3):

I would be interested to understand your workflow a bit better, but to try and help with your specific request:

- The HYPERLINK solution proposed in the comments looks like a good one
- If you are able to implement that upstream in the csv generation step then great
- If not and/or you are interested in automating the conversion process, consider using the pandas library:

  - Create a DataFrame object from a csv using the [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method
  - Convert your paths to HYPERLINKs
  - Write back to xlsx using the [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method

E.g. if you have a file original.csv and the relevant column header is file_paths:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('original.csv')
df['file_paths'] = '=HYPERLINK("' + df['file_paths'] + '")'
df.to_excel('new.xlsx', index=False)
```

Hope that helps!

Jon